# java output html code to file

Tags: java, html, printing

I have a chunk of html code that should be outputted as a .html file, in java. The pre-written html code is the header and table for a page, and i need to generate some data, and output it to the same .html file. Is there an easier way to print the html code than to do prinln() line by line? Thanks

Comment: In what form is the "chunk of html" now? Is it in a file?  If so, you could just open the file and copy it to stdout. Take a look at http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: You mentioned that output will be saved back to the same html file...does that mean that you have another source that generates the the base HTML file(s) for you to consume?

Comment: the chunk of html is actually the header for the output HTML file, and yes, the rest of the file is generated from another source file (plain text). 
What I need to do is convert a directory of files into html, each having the same header. That is why I want to know how to print a bunch of html code into a file

Answer (score 0):

You can look at some Java libraries for parsing HTML code. A quick Google search tuns up a few. Read in the HTML and then use their queries to manipulate the DOM as needed and then spit it back out.
e.g. http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Did I misunderstand the OP?

So you have some "pre-written" HTML code stored in a file or a String or somewhere. Read it into the HTML parsing library. Then "generate some data" as prescribed. Inject the data as necessary. Use the library to output the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a templating engine, [MVEL2](http://mvel.codehaus.org/) or [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/), for example. Both can be used by standalone applications outside of a web framework. You lose time upfront but it will save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

JSP (Java Server Pages) allows you to write HTML files which have some Java code easily embedded within them. For example

```
<html><head><title>Hi!</title></head><body>
<% some java code here that outputs some stuff %>
</body></html>
```

Though that requires that you have an enterprise Java server installed. But if this is on a web server, that might not be unreasonable to have.

If you want to do it in normal Java, that depends. I don't fully understand which part you meant you will be outputting line by line. Did you mean you are going to do something like

```
System.out.println("<html>");
System.out.println("<head><title>Hi!</title></head>");
System.out.println("<body>");
// etc
```

Like that? If that's what you meant, then don't do that. You can just read in the data from the template file and output all the data at once. You could read it into a multiline text string of you could read the data in from the template and output it directly to the new file. Something like

```
while( (strInput = templateFileReader.readLine()) != null)
    newFileOutput.println(strInput);
```

Again, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that part.

Comment: Yeah your second suggestion is what I meant, except the HTML code is hard-coded into the program. What I need to do is output the hard-coded HTML (the header), then generate rest of the page based on command line input. What i'm writing is actually a javas program, sorry for the confusion

Comment: When you say it's hard-coded into the program, I'm assuming it's stored in a String or something. So couldn't you just do: `newFileOutput.println(header);` and then proceed to print out the rest of the page?

Comment: That's what i'm currently doing, but it's really slow to type every line by itself... Just wondering if there is a quicker method

Answer (score 0):

HTML is simply a way of marking up text, so to write a HTML file, you are simply writing the HTML as text to a file with the .html extension.

There's plenty of tutorials out there for reading and writing from files, as well as getting a list of files from a directory.  (Google 'java read file', 'java write file', 'java list directory' - that is basically everything you need.)  The important thing is the use of BufferedReader/BufferedWriter for pulling and pushing the text in to the files and realising that there is no particular code science involved in writing HTML to a file.

I'll reiterate; HTML is nothing more than `<b>text with tags</b>`.

Here's a really crude example that will output two files to a single file, wrapping them in an `<html></html>` tag.

```
BufferedReader getReaderForFile(filename) {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
}

public void main(String[] args) {
    // Open a file
    BufferedReader myheader = getReaderForFile("myheader.txt");
    BufferedReader contents = getReaderForFile("contentfile.txt");

    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("mypage.html");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

    out.write("<html>");
    out.newLine();

    for (String line = myheader.readLine(); line!=null; line = myheader.readLine()) {
        out.write(line);
        out.newLine(); // readLine() strips 'carriage return' characters
    }

    for (String line = contents.readLine(); line!=null; line = contents.readLine()) {
        out.write(line);
        out.newLine(); // readLine() strips 'carriage return' characters
    }

    out.write("</html>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To build a simple HTML text file, you don't have to read your input file line by line.

```
  File theFile = new File("file.html");
  byte[] content = new byte[(int) theFile.length()];
```

You can use "[RandomAccessFile.readFully](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readFully(byte[]))" to read files entirely as a byte array:

```
  // Read file function:
  RandomAccessFile file = null;
  try {
    file = new RandomAccessFile(theFile, "r");
    file.readFully(content);
  } finally {
    if(file != null) {
      file.close();
    }
  }
```

Make your modifications on the text content:

```
  String text = new String(content);
  text = text.replace("<!-- placeholder -->", "generated data");
  content = text.getBytes();
```

Writing is also easy:

```
  // Write file content:
  RandomAccessFile file = null;
  try {
    file = new RandomAccessFile(theFile, "rw");
    file.write(content);
  } finally {
    if(file != null) {
      file.close();
    }
  }
```